# Wait for a thread to finish before passing the value

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a telegram bot that can search Wikipedia with telegram api and vb.net. If someone sends a message saying "wiki xyz" (telegram api, Onmessage)bot gives info about xyz. The problem is about simultaneous messages, if a user with a specific chat ID requests a wiki search and while its in progess if a second (or even third) requests the same then the chat ID and the wiki search term gets mixed up. How to wait for the first user's request being processed and sent before processing the second(or even 3rd) request?

Here is the code

```
Private Async Sub OnMessageReceived(sender  As Object, e As MessageEventArgs)
Dim sender As String = e.Message.From.Id.ToString 
Dim msg As String = e.Message.Body.toString
If msg.StartsWith("wiki") Then
  Dim query as String= msg.replace("wiki","")

'''do Wikipedia search with query and sending the reply to sender

            Await sendMessage(sender, formattedWikitxt.ToString)
    End If
```

the problem is that while receiving simultaneous requests, the variables "sender" and "query" gets changed before the message is delivered and users are getting some other query in reply instead. How to make this task wait before the first user receives message before processing the request of the second(or even 3rd)?

Comment: your question sounds interesting and relevant, but in order to help you try to add here any code you have already wrote and what part goes wrong. trying reading the help section, especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There are so, so many ways to do what you want. Without seeing your current code it's hard to provide an answer that will be useful to you and to future readers. Right now this question is off-topic for SO as it is too broad. Please provide some code to help us help you.

Comment: _"while receiving simultaneous requests, the variables "sender" and "query" gets changed"_ I haven't used that API before but in general this shouldn't really happen. Both `sender` (which needs another name, btw) and `query` are local variables and shouldn't get changed by another code. Note that when a new message is received and `OnMessageReceived` gets triggered again, that's a new method with new local variables (i.e., `sender` and `query`). Are you sure nothing else is going on in your code which alters the values of said variables?